# Path to content folder in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to read a .txt file in my program:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/txt/FamilyNames.txt")))
                    {
                        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Debug.WriteLine(line);
                    }
```

This however gives me following path, which is incorrect:

> C:\Content\txt\FamilyNames.txt

When I search for this I come up with numerous solutions like:

```
Server.MapPath();
```

But this seems to be outdated code? Because it doesn't get recognized in my Visual Studio, can't import it...

So what is the correct solution to get a path to a file in the content folder?

Comment: Maybe you are outside of the controller. To use **Server.MapPath** outside of controller you need to use it like HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()

Comment: Where are you calling that from?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath() did it, simple ... :)

Comment: ToAbsolute() ? is it not a relative path your are looking for ?

Comment: Yeah, this was just one of the numerous solutions I tried.

Answer (score 16):

Server.MapPath needs a HTTPContext. Use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath` instead.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/txt/FamilyNames.txt")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
 StreamReader(VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~/Content/txt/FamilyNames.txt")))
```